# how to install a src .rpm

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded a source rmp src.rpm file of audacity 
when i run `[root@09PC148B Downloads]# rpmbuild --rebuild audacity-2.1.0-2.fc23.src.rpm`
this is the response i am getting

```
flac-devel is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
    jack-audio-connection-kit-devel is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
    ladspa-devel is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
    libid3tag-devel is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
    taglib-devel is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
    libogg-devel is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
    libsndfile-devel is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
    libvorbis-devel is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
    portaudio-devel >= 19-16 is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
    soundtouch-devel is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
    soxr-devel is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
    vamp-plugin-sdk-devel >= 2.0 is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
    wxGTK-devel is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
    libappstream-glib is needed by audacity-2.1.0-2.el6.i686
```

when i run this command

```
[root@09PC148B Downloads]# rpm -ivv audacity-2.1.0-2.fc23.src.rpm
my resonse is 
D: ============== audacity-2.1.0-2.fc23.src.rpm
D: loading keyring from pubkeys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: couldn't find any keys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: loading keyring from rpmdb
D: opening  db environment /var/lib/rpm cdb:mpool:joinenv
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages rdonly mode=0x0
D: locked   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name rdonly mode=0x0
D:  read h#    1438 Header sanity check: OK
D: added key gpg-pubkey-6b8d79e6-3f49313d to keyring
D: Using legacy gpg-pubkey(s) from rpmdb
D: Expected size:     24389466 = lead(96)+sigs(4292)+pad(4)+data(24385074)
D:   Actual size:     24389466
D: audacity-2.1.0-2.fc23.src.rpm: Header SHA1 digest: OK (6b5705fc00764be7bc14578e1976d33d86ac2a3d)
D:  added source package [0]
D: found 1 source and 0 binary packages
D: Expected size:     24389466 = lead(96)+sigs(4292)+pad(4)+data(24385074)
D:   Actual size:     24389466
D: InstallSourcePackage at: psm.c:244: Header SHA1 digest: OK (6b5705fc00764be7bc14578e1976d33d86ac2a3d)
audacity-2.1.0-2.fc23
D: ========== Directories not explicitly included in package:
D:          0 /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/
D:          1 /root/rpmbuild/SPECS/
D: ==========
D: fini      100664  1 ( 501, 501)  19390331 /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/audacity-manual-2.1.0.zip;55486cb6 unknown
D: fini      100664  1 ( 501, 501)   5104924 /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/audacity-minsrc-2.1.0.tar.xz;55486cb6 unknown
D: fini      100644  1 ( 501, 501)     23062 /root/rpmbuild/SPECS/audacity.spec;55486cb6 unknown
GZDIO:    2994 reads, 24518844 total bytes in 0.074680 secs
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: closed   db environment /var/lib/rpm
```

what is the error

Answer (score 0):

You need to install dependent packages before build the required one
Try to use

```
yum install <package>
```

this will take care about the dependencies

Comment: when i download the supporting (dependent )package ,it is asking for some other package for installation

Comment: etting requirements for audacity-2.1.0-2.fc23.src
 --> Already installed : alsa-lib-devel-1.0.22-3.el6.i686
 --> Already installed : desktop-file-utils-0.15-9.el6.i686
 --> Already installed : expat-devel-2.0.1-11.el6_2.i686
Error: No Package found for flac-devel  when i try to insatll flac-devel-1.3.1-1.fc21.i686 it is popping up error like this   flac-devel-1.3.1-1.fc21.i686 requires pkgconfig(ogg)
flac-devel-1.3.1-1.fc21.i686 requires flac-libs(x86-32) = 1.3.1-1.fc21

Comment: is there any way to get all the supporting packages for auda city in a single step

Comment: You can use this command: yum localinstall /path/to/rpm/package.prm